# Python requests - request returns as successful, but the content was not uploaded

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to send a post request on a website named [www.bazos.sk](http://www.bazos.sk) , the post returns code 200, so it was successful, but the content (in this case, I'm trying to send an advertisement) was not uploaded.
Where did I mess up?

(The contents of the key-value pairs are fake, so they are not personal data)

```
import requests


url = 'https://deti.bazos.sk/pridat-inzerat.php'

data = {
    'category': '122',
    'nadpis': 'test', #nadpis = title
    'popis': 'test', #popis = description
    'cena': '1', #cena = price
    'cenavyber': '1', #cenavyber = choosable price
    'lokalita': '03403', #lokalita = place of the advertisement
    'jmeno': 'Robert', #jmeno = name
    'telefoni': '8374827543', #telefoni = phone number
    'maili': 'fakemail@gmail.com', #maili = mail
    'heslobazar': 'FakePassword2', #heslobazar = password
    'werwe': 'fsfwereg', 
    'Submit': 'Odoslať'
}

print("Processing...")

response = requests.post(url, data=data)
print(response.status_code, response.reason)

input("Press [ENTER] to quit")
```

**SOLVED**: [Python requests - Website says missing data, what data is missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71414485/python-requests-website-says-missing-data-what-data-is-missing)

Comment: This depends on how the website handles these requests, which we do not know.

Comment: I tested it, i can easily remove advertisements with python requests, but i can't upload them.

Comment: You may want to pass the `data` dict as the parameter `json` of `post()`. It handles the serialization to JSON and sets the correct content-type header. E.G: `requests.post(url, json=data)`

Comment: I did tried that EDG956, it didn't helped.

Comment: Are you sure the url is right?  The question says `www.bazos`, but the code has `deti.bazos`.

Comment: Yes, it is right, this advertisement website uses different urls for different advertisement types; like: auto.bazos.sk for cars, deti.bazos.sk for stuff for kids